# Why is wau not equal to one?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, arithmetic, constants

As said in this video below,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFLkou8NvJo

The number 1 satisfies every single property of wau.

eg: first answer by Patrick Yu in the below question:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-number-Wau

So what's so special about wau? Isn't it equal to one?

Comment: Yes, it is $1$. She is just being playful.

Comment: It actually equals 0.999999... :)

Answer (score 2):

What Vi Hart did was  pretty much the same as what the people behind [dihydrogen monoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydrogen_monoxide_hoax) (written out, it looks like H$_2$O) did. She just hid the name behind something really cool sounding as a joke.